# Testing Hybrid Android Apps (get WebView components)

Tags: android, testing, webview, hybrid

I am creating a hybrid Android app.  That is, most of the work is done in HTML5, CSS and JavaScript and our app is essentially a full screen WebView. I am using the android JavaScript bridge extensively to talk back and forth between native Android and the WebView.

Now on to testing. What is the best way to test this bridge?  What is the CLEANEST way to control the HTML elements in my tests?  Say I have an HTML5 button. How do I click it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at [MonkeyTalk](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk), which has support for testing hybrid applications. While their recorder won't work, you can manually modify the test script to interact with the html elements.

Further documentation here:
http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk/documentation/scripting-hybrid-nativehtml-apps

Answer (score 1):

try calabash. I was using it for a while previously to test HTML rendered in webview.

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios